# Get name of focused control on the Form

Tags: c#, combobox, focus, controls

Is it even possible to get the name of the `ComboBox` that is focused? I would like a label to show the name.

Comment: Which UI framework? Winforms? WPF or what?

Comment: Windows Form Application

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lets say you have 3 comboboxes on your form and a label.

Add the code for a combobox enter event.
And in this code you will use the sender to get the name of the combobox and display it in the label.

```
private void CBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control CBox = (Control)sender;
        label1.Text = CBox.Name;
    }
```

Then you need to select all the comboboxes you want to use, to add CBox_Enter to all the comboboxes enter event.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the `this.ActiveControl` and this is a `Control` and you can cast it to `ComboBox`

Comment: I support this answer. For future readers: Prefer this over accepted answer.

Comment: But how can you use that? I am pretty new at this, so i dont now how to implement this code?

Comment: `yourLabel.Text = (this.ActiveControl as ComboBox).Name;` . But you must note that if this code is in the button click event, the button was focused.